# How to combine multiple rows of text in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a VERY large SQL database that stores a text field into multiple rows with a sequence number. I need to find a way to write SQL code to combine all of those sequence notes into one cohesive notes field for a view.

Data source resembles this: [Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdtS0.png)
Desired output resembles this: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMwLb.png)

I'm relatively new to SQL so I'm honestly not sure where to begin with combining this. In other languages I'd write an iterative loop, but I'm not sure how to make anything like that happen in SQL.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Please learn how to ask a proper question here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment:  [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB syntax can vary, but in general the standard SQL function `LISTAGG` does what you want.

In your case, you want something like

```
select date, icn, count(sequence) as "Sequence Count", 
       listagg(notes, ' ') within group (order by sequence) as notes
from table
group by date, icn;
```

If it's possible that you can have multiple dates for the same ICN entry, then you might need to `group by icn` and apply an aggregate function (e.g. `max`) to the date column.

LISTAGG often has length limits, and not all DBs support it, so you'll probably need to tag your specific database to get a more comprehensive answer.

Also a general note to look into - whenever you would want to use an iterative loop, usually in SQL that means a `group by` and an aggregate or window function.